# Problem function trying to transform a string with letter into string with only "*"

Tags: python, string, function

i've coded a function to get a word by an input of the users and i've to retake my result in one of my function and use it to get another functions working but when i try i get a lot of errors but in vs code it tells me that i dont have any errors. I dont understand why it does something like this
Here's my code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def essais(question1="Combien d'essai ? ", question2="Saisie invalide veuillez recommencez : Combien d'essai ? "):
    essai = input(question1)  # demande un numéro
    while not essai.isnumeric():
        # si saisie non valide alors répeté la question et récuperer le numéro
        essai = input(question2)
    print(str(essai) + ' essai(s).')

essais()

def majuscule(mot):

    if mot.isalpha():   #isalpha sert a savoir si c'est uniquement des lettres dans la chaine de caractères
        print("Mot valide")
    else:
        mot = input("Quel mot voulez vous faire devinez ? ")

    resultat = ""


    for i in range(len(mot)):
        caractere = mot[i]
        if (ord(caractere) >= ord("a")) and (ord(caractere) <= ord("z")):  # si on détecte une minuscule
            valeur_lettre = ord(caractere)
            valeur_lettre -= 32  # equivalent en maj
            # transfo valeur de la lettre minuscule en lettre maj
            caractere = chr(valeur_lettre)

        resultat += caractere
      #i've done my function like that because i was told to do it like that without using the upper function built-in. 
    print(resultat)
    return resultat



majuscule(mot=input("Quel mot voulez vous faire devinez ? "))

def mot_cacher(resultat):
    mot_cache=""
    for n in range(len(resultat)):
        mot_cache +="*"
    print(mot_cache)
    
    #fonction for getting my word transcripted into "*"
```

I tried using a variable when I called my functions and it works it transform my word into * but when I tried anything else I got a lot of errors like:

```
TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()
```

etc...

I just want that my function reused my variable `resultat` and transforms it into all the length of the word and return it to me.

Comment: How did you call `mot_cacher`?

Comment: i just put ```mot_cacher(resultat)```

Comment: `resultat` is not define in your code. Please add the missing line(s) and error full trace (which include which line include the error)

Comment: maybe you need to save the output of `majuscule`, smt like `resultat = majuscule(...)`

Comment: i got an error on line 44 in ```mot_cacher``` about ```for n in range(len(resultat)):``` and i got this error ```TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()``` 
and on line 50 when i do ```mot_cacher(resultat)```

Comment: and with `resultat=(majuscule(mot=input("...")` it works without any errors.

Comment: so, problem fix?

Answer (score 0):

I'll do like that thanks to cards for helping me :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



def essais(question1="Combien d'essai ? ", question2="Saisie invalide veuillez recommencez : Combien d'essai ? "):
    essai = input(question1)  # demande un numéro
    while not essai.isnumeric():
        # si saisie non valide alors répeté la question et récuperer le numéro
        essai = input(question2)
    print(str(essai) + ' essai(s).')

essais()

def majuscule(mot):

    if mot.isalpha():   #isalpha sert a savoir si c'est uniquement des lettres dans la chaine de caractères
        print("Mot valide")
    else:
        mot = input("Quel mot voulez vous faire devinez ? ")

    resultat = ""

    #print("Merci Florence de ton aide précieuse ! ")


    for i in range(len(mot)):
        caractere = mot[i]
        if (ord(caractere) >= ord("a")) and (ord(caractere) <= ord("z")):  # si on détecte une minuscule
            valeur_lettre = ord(caractere)
            valeur_lettre -= 32  # equivalent en maj
            # transfo valeur de la lettre minuscule en lettre maj
            caractere = chr(valeur_lettre)

        resultat += caractere

    print(resultat)
    return resultat


resultat=(majuscule(mot=input("Quel mot voulez vous faire devinez ? "))) #just this line change 

def mot_cacher(resultat):
    mot_cache=""
    for n in range(len(resultat)):
        mot_cache +="*"
    print(mot_cache)
    
    

mot_cacher(resultat)
```

just my line 40 change and pass from this `majuscule(mot=input("Quel mot voulez vous faire devinez ? "))` to this : `resultat=(majuscule(mot=input("Quel mot voulez vous faire devinez ? ")))`